# Why does not blockarray align when used in array?

Tags: math-mode, arrays, blkarray

In the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{r@{\;=\;}l}
    c & \begin{blockarray}{[c]c}
          0 & \scriptstyle m_1
        \end{blockarray}
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

the result is

[image]

Why doesn't the `blkarray` align with *c*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a surprise, I'm afraid: `blkarray` uses several tricks that end up using a bounding box that's not necessarily the expected one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}

X$\begin{blockarray}{[c]c} 0 & \scriptstyle m_1 \end{blockarray}$X

X\fbox{$\begin{blockarray}{[c]c} 0 & \scriptstyle m_1 \end{blockarray}$}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

In *this particular case*, not tested in different situations, you can do by moving the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\newenvironment{adjblockarray}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\adjblockarraybox}$\begin{blockarray}}
 {\end{blockarray}$\end{lrbox}%
  \raisebox{-1ex}[\dimexpr\height-1ex][\dimexpr\depth-1ex]{\usebox{\adjblockarraybox}}}
\newsavebox{\adjblockarraybox}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}

X$\begin{blockarray}{[c]c} 0 & \scriptstyle m_1 \end{blockarray}$X

X$\begin{adjblockarray}{[c]c} 0 & \scriptstyle m_1 \end{adjblockarray}$X

X\fbox{$\begin{adjblockarray}{[c]c} 0 & \scriptstyle m_1 \end{adjblockarray}$}X

\[
\begin{array}{r@{\;=\;}l}
c & \begin{adjblockarray}{[c]c}
    0 & \scriptstyle m_1
   \end{adjblockarray}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I modified your `adjblockarray` to take an extra argument to represent the offset. This was exactly what I needed.